# Is there a standard way to document recursive functions?

Tags: javascript, recursion

Just wondering if there is a standard notation or at least a common notation for specifying a recursive function?

I don't know if it's important, but I like to give as much information in my function docblocks as possible, so I will usually just add something like 'This is a recursive function'.

Here is an example so we're all thinking about documenting in the same place. And my example is using ES2015 Javascript

```js
/**
 * Replace $nbsp;'s with actual spaces and return the message
 *
 * Recursive
 *
 * @param {string} message The string to be cleaned
 *
 * @returns {string}
 * @private
 */
_replaceSpaces(string) {
  const cleanedString = string.replace('&nbsp;', ' ');
  if (cleanedString.indexOf('&nbsp;') > -1) {
    return this._replaceSpaces(cleanedString);
  }

  return cleanedString;
}
```

Comment: Why does a user of your function care whether it uses recursion internally? You might as well say "This function uses a local variable called `i`" or something.

Comment: That's a pretty terrible implementation. It would be better to use a simple `while` loop, and even more better to not call `.indexOf` in a loop because that makes its runtime quadratic: `return string.replace(/&nbsp;/g, ' ');`

Comment: @melpomene I had been trying the regex with the global flag the other day and it wasn't working, so I gave up on it in favour of just looping.. I will try it again to see if I have just typed something wrong

Answer (score 1):

The fact that your function uses recursion or not isn't something that the user of that function should care. This is more for your own self to be reminded of, and doesn't need to be mentioned in the docs.

Whether using recursion in this particular case is the best approach is another matter.

**Update**
Doind a regex string replacement should do the job.

```
str.replace(/&nbsp;/g, ' ')
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on your point about whether this is or isn't the best approach? I'm assuming you have another, better approach?

Edit:
Nevermind, other people have posted

Answer (score 0):

I'm always a bit surprised when I drill down into a function and slowly come to realize it's the same function I was already looking at/stepping through. I'm expecting a normal extracted or overloaded function, not a self call. So I like to put a comment like this right at the site of recursion:

```
if (cleanedString.indexOf('&nbsp;') > -1) {
    // Recursively continue removing spaces.
    return this._replaceSpaces(cleanedString);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know, but I like this question and think it's important.

Answering this for myself, I watched some YouTube on "how to write recursion functions" videos and like my college text books they all agreed.  Two important factors exist in all recursive functions; they are:

- a base case
- a recursive procedure

So in addition to your documentation, I could suggest also highlighting the parts of your code that fulfill these two concepts.  It would be effective and communicative, I think, to those familiar to writing recursive functions and computer
science majors.